# Unlocking Samsung Galaxy S7 with broken screen plugged into computer

Tags: linux, broken-screen, samsung-galaxy-s7

The screen on my phone is broken, and there are a few files I'd like to get off of it. I don't care about the phone at all, just the files. I know the password, I just can't enter it on the broken screen.

I can plug the device into my computer, and it recognizes it, but I can't unlock it, so my computer cannot copy files off of it.

`lsusb` lists it as `Bus 001 Device 097: ID 04e8:6860 Samsung Electronics Co., Ltd Galaxy (MTP)`.

`adb devices` unfortunately doesn't recognize my phone, presumably since it's locked.

It's possible there's more damage to my phone than just the screen, not sure though since it won't turn on.

Any advice would be appreciated, I don't even really know where to start.

Comment: https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/159551

Comment: @alecxs thanks, hopefully I can get that working

Comment: try with working device first, you just have one try

Answer (score 0):

A bit late to the party but you can unlock your phone with [find my phone](https://findmymobile.samsung.com/)
That wasn't enough in my case.

Most recovery tools require you to have usb debugging enabled before you break your phone.