# How do I access the files on my broken Huawei phone without HiSuite?

Tags: huawei, broken-screen

I accidentally threw my phone onto the road today and now the screen is completely unusable - fully cracked all over, fully black, light still shines from the back light but there is nothing on screen at all. I want to save my music and photos, but when I connect my phone to my computer I have to use HiSuite to get to my files. As I can't go into my phone and give HiSuite the permission to go through my files, I'm stuck. Is there really no alternative way to get my files back on my Huawei device?

I've done some research and apparently you have to download HiSuite's drivers but not the program - unfortunately I'm not tech savvy enough to understand exactly what that entails. I'm sure there's a simple solution to my problem that I'm missing and I hope you can help me out!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Enable ADB and/or change USB connection mode on Galaxy S7 w/ broken screen](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/159551/enable-adb-and-or-change-usb-connection-mode-on-galaxy-s7-w-broken-screen)

Comment: it's not that easy. the goal is to enable usb-debugging. if you can get similar device it can help you operate blind, if you do same actions on both devices simultaneously