# How to recover data from phone with black screen?

Tags: data-recovery, usb-debugging, broken-screen, samsung-galaxy-s-6, usb-drivers

My Samsung Galaxy S6 recently display doesn't work anymore (apparently it's water damage or something). The problem is, I want to extract my photos but it's like shooting targets in the dark. I've successfully unlocked my phone with "Find My Mobile" by Samsung but when I connect my phone to my computer with USB, it is unrecognized. I think there may be a prompt on my phone which asks for permission, but again, I can't see anything. How do I solve this?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Enable ADB and/or change USB connection mode on Galaxy S7 w/ broken screen](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/159551/enable-adb-and-or-change-usb-connection-mode-on-galaxy-s7-w-broken-screen)

Comment: your only chance is acting blind. i don't believe there is a prompt for connecting, instead there is still some lock screen (now from Find My Mobile)

Comment: Our [broken-screen tag wiki](/tags/broken-screen/info) is a good starting point. It even has a data recovery section.