# Why my tablet shows black screen

Tags: screen, tablet, backlight

i am facing a weird problem with a chinese tablet,my tablet seems to be working normally i can hear sounds and the backlights works but it shows nothing,i though it was flex cable problem so i replaced it but the problem is not gone then i tryed three LCD screens but it was the same .

how can is diagonse this problem?

Comment: not a solution but you can use [scrcpy](https://www.xda-developers.com/scrcpy-control-android-on-pc) if you still have black screen even on remote PC then you know it is not a screen problem. but can be still hardware or software error

Comment: usb debugging is not activated in my tablet 

Comment: does it support USB OTG or is it Mediatek Chipset?

Comment: yes it supports USB OTG and has an intel cpu .

Comment: guess you want recover data? when you can hear sound it may possible to navigate blind with connected keyboard. but you need another tablet for reference https://android.stackexchange.com/q/159551

Comment: thankyou for your response ,i wish i could find out  what causes this problem.