# Pull Text Messages from a phone with broken screen

Tags: sms, usb-debugging, broken-screen

I need the text messages from the stock texting app on my broken Galaxy Note8. The screen is damaged in a way where installing any app to transfer the data from the phone is impossible. I'm hoping the texts are stored somewhere I can access from my computer via USB.

I don't know where to look or if I need some specific program on my computer to reach the location they are stored in. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Have you enabled Android Developer menu and adb on the device when the screen was working? If yes you could not connect your phone to your computer, see the screen and use your mouse to navigate via [scrcpy](https://github.com/Genymobile/scrcpy/releases).

Comment: https://android.stackexchange.com/q/159551

Comment: Have you seen our [broken-screen tag wiki](/tags/broken-screen/info) yet? And its data recovery section? And… [How do I backup data (SMS/contacts) from a device with a broken screen?](https://android.stackexchange.com/q/25646/16575)