# Data recover with broken screen

Tags: recovery-mode, data-recovery, broken-screen, oneplus-3

yesterday my beloved OnePlus 3T fell and the screen cracked :(
At first half of it was still usable and visible, shame on me for not recovering the data I needed at that time. now the upper half is still usable but completely black, also the battery died without me noticing so it turned off.

Now I'm stuck with the following situation: phone is turned on, but the pin is preventing me from logging in (I can't type the pin blindly as the bottom half of the screen doesn't get touch inputs), the pc doesn't recognize the phone beyond the driver "disk", so sending commands via adb it's not an option.

I tried booting in recovery mode with volume down+power and I think it got booted in recovery, but I don't remember If I can use the buttons to navigate it. I pressed volume down 3 times to move to english, pressed power to select english, pressed power to select "install from adb", pressed power to select "Ok". at this point I expected the phone to be visible (assuming everything is set up correctly on the pc) when running "adb devices" on cmd, but it doesn't. can anyone confirm that these steps are correct?

I'll later try an otg cable and connect mouse/keyboard as a last resort.

I'm running out of ideas, so if anyone has any idea on how to recover files (don't care about contacts and stuff) from the phone is more than welcome.

Comment: If your device is protected by a PIN/password, then the USB OTG keyboard is the way to go. After authentication via PIN adb should be usable again. Additionally you can check out or [broken-screen tag wiki](https://android.stackexchange.com/tags/broken-screen/info).

Comment: if you still can see something try to enable usb-debugging with OTG Keyboard. once you authorized adb you can use [scrcpy](https://www.xda-developers.com/scrcpy-control-android-on-pc) to get full control

Comment: @alecxs unfortunately I can't see anything anymore

Comment: you need second device to figure out key sequence. first test on working device. then you can do it blind https://android.stackexchange.com/q/159551

Comment: @alecxs will try

Comment: turns out otg doesn't even work... I guess that's really the end :(