# I want to restore my contacts from a broken and black screen android device

Tags: adb, samsung-galaxy-s-5, broken-screen

I have a Samsung galaxy s5. Its screen has gotten smashed and now it displays nothing (black).

I can turn on the phone, and also I can enter recovery mode (by pressing home+power+volume up).

I have ADB installed on my laptop. But ADB can not access my phone and it shows it is unauthorized after typing `adb devices`, because it needs debugging mode to be enabled on the phone and I can not do that because the screen is smashed and black.

I have read that after entering recovery mode in your phone you can access it with ADB without USB debugging being enabled. So I entered recovery mode in my S5 then I connected it to my laptop, in my laptop I typed `adb devices` but nothing was shown. Does somebody know how to do it?

Is there any better solution?

Comment: You need a custom recovery already installed/flashed to access your data through recovery mode. If you did not do it earlier (before the event that smashed your screen) or if you don't understand what I am saying, than it means that recovery mode technique is a dead end now. Did you not use a Google account in your device and synced your data (including contacts) with your Google account? If you did, you can try finding them at contacts.google.com

Comment: Actually I did not install custom recovery before my screen got smashed. But I have 2 questions please, first how can install/flash a custom recovery in order to access my data through recovery mode? If the recovery mode technique is a dead end now, what can I do else?

Comment: Like I said, try the Google contacts route if you had sync enabled or at least a Google account added into your device. As for flashing a custom recovery, you can try searching for that on the web, but I wouldn't suggest going down that path. Not only do you have a broken screen which would frustrate the hell out of you when following tedious instructions, flashing recovery often require unlocking bootloader which would DELETE your data altogether, so proceed with the instructions elsewhere with extreme caution.

Comment: Is trying to unlock the screen code a good idea? (since when the screen is unlocked, you can access phone data on the laptop)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Enable ADB and/or change USB connection mode on Galaxy S7 w/ broken screen](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/159551/enable-adb-and-or-change-usb-connection-mode-on-galaxy-s7-w-broken-screen)