# How options do I have for data recovery for my Samsunge Note 4?

Tags: data-recovery

The screen on my Samsung Note 4 cracked. Unfortunately, I did not back up the data in internal memory before that happened. Although the phone works, I have no way to access my data since I don't have a screen.

I am trying to determine what the best path forward is for recovering my data. These are the options I have identified as of the the moment.

- I have an extra note 4 lying around and thought it might be possible to try and switch the screens, but I am not sure if that is easily doable.
- Have a professional recover the data for me.

If anyone knows of other options then please let me know. For example, if there is a way to access the contents of the phone without a screen that would be really helpful.

Which is the best path forward? Should I just bite the bullet and pay for recovery services?

Comment: https://android.stackexchange.com/q/159551 you have a second device - perfect for doing things "blind"

Comment: even more lucky your devices support MHL 3 TV-out, just need MHL compatible TV or [MHL to HDMI adapter](https://www.amazon.de/dp/B01GPUQIH2) and [connect](https://www.amazon.de/dp/B01MQF3AP0) monitor + mouse + keyboard with [OTG hub](https://www.amazon.de/dp/B078M3Z84Z)